# Client Server secure login

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, authorization

I have a question about client server architecture.  I use C# .Net in the client and the server.  The logic runs serverside and the inputs and results only run via the client.  Now I have something that's worrying me.  Let's assume the client logs in and sends the input as json to the server and the server processes the input (which is not a problem on the server side).  The login is successful and the server returns the status code 101 for a successful login and sends this back to the client.

Now we come to the part that worries me.  I don't know exactly how the client should process these responses.  An if statement that checks whether the string = 101, is not really safe.  What exactly would the client have to do to ensure that the login is successful?  In this case, the client is not trustworthy and I want to avoid hacking my program.

I was thinking about adding the username with a guid to a list in the server when a successful login occurs.  And to check every incoming request in this way.But somehow that doesn't solve my client side problem

Can someone maybe give me a suggestion what I can do to prevent from hacking.

Comment: You'll want to do some studying on both authentication and authorization (these are two different but related topics) in ASP.NET. In short, you protect your server endpoints by checking the authorization of the authenticated user (ASP.NET has a lot of this logic built in, you just have to wire everything up). Some of the particulars will depend on who is your identity provider (if not your server itself). Do not try to roll your own IDP.

Comment: If authentication and authorization is done properly on the server side (and you aren't leaking any secrets, etc), it doesn't really matter what a bad actor does with your client code. They won't be able to do or see anything that they shouldn't

Comment: @Luke is 100% spot on. DO NOT try to roll your own authentication. ASP.Net has standards that manage this for you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: You're right, I don't need to reinvent the wheel. I'll check it, thanks 